# Split action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splitactionbar

i split action Bar on my activity.
However it looks like this on galaxy S4 i9500:
[image]

How it looks like on a 5.5 inch screen:
[image]

Is there a way to split the actionbar on big screens too?
Please help. got to release the apk today :/

Comment: Sometimes images *don't* explain everything. Show us how you're loading/changing the tabs/fragments.

Comment: Nope, as far as I know, split actionbar works only on phones, not with tablets.

Comment: any other solution to fix this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Not without rolling your own layouts and back end code.  The splitActionBarWhenNarrow is intended to adapt to the screen size according to whether or not you have enough horizontal space.  The developer doesn't have any more control than that guidance.  Different behavior would be a deviation from the default behavior of many other applications' ActionBar.  Personally, I would advise against it and go with what [splitActionBarWhenNarrow](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#uioptions) gives you.